# Can I create many stylesheet files with SASS or LESS?

Tags: css, sass, less

I've different color palettes on my webpage, they can be changed in user control panel. I want create my CSS files with SASS or LESS (This is preparations in this moment, so CSS preprocessor will be selected later). It's possible to generate many CSS files - for colors and for content?

Comment: Not 100% sure what you are asking but the answer is most likely yes

Comment: Yes you can use compilers to compile your LESS or SASS to CSS. Personally I use WebEssentials to compile LESS to CSS and minified CSS in visual studio.

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for either preprocessor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah.  So LESS and SASS both work by having a main file import other files.  If you have 'theme1.less' and 'theme2.less' both can import 'variables.less', 'mixins.less', 'whatever.less'.  Any LESS file can import any other. Read more about LESS at http://lesscss.org and about SASS at http://sass-lang.com.